# Iterating over a directory and getting UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java

So, I am currently writing a method to iterate over a directory and all directory's inside of that directory:

```java
public static Set<File> iterateDirectory(String dir){
    Set<File> children = new HashSet<>();
    File dirc = new File(Windows.home + dir);
    File[] dircList = dirc.listFiles();
    List<File> l = Arrays.asList(dircList);
    for (File c : l){
        if(c.isDirectory()){
            if (c.listFiles().length != 0) {
                List x = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(c.listFiles()));
                if (!x.isEmpty()){
                    l.addAll(x);
                }
            }
        }else {
            children.add(c);
        }
    }
    return children;
}
```

Now when I try to compile and run this it throws me the following error:(I am not sure if it works at this moment due to me receiving the error.)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
    at org.thesecretintelligence.xx.Xx.iterateDirectory(Xx.java:20) <- (Line 20 pointed out below)
    at org.thesecretintelligence.xx.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

the line causing the error is this -> `l.addAll(x);`.

I unfortunately have not tried anything else.

Thanks a lot, I hope someone knows what is causing this.

EDIT:

After being told a Queue was better then a List I tried the following:

```java
    public static Set<File> iterateDirectory(String dir){
        Set<File> children = new HashSet<>();
        File dirc = new File(Windows.home + dir);
        File[] dircList = dirc.listFiles();
        Queue<File> l = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(dircList));
        for (File c : l){
            if(c.isDirectory()){
                if (c.listFiles().length != 0) {
                    ((LinkedList<File>) l).addAll(Arrays.asList(c.listFiles()));
                }
            }else {
                children.add(c);
            }
        }
        return children;
    }
```

and received a error - `Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`, I am assuming this is because I am changing the values while looping through them, is there any way you guys can recommend me bypass this / work around it?

Comment: Maybe List.addAll(List) doesn't exist?

Comment: @FailingCoder - of course it exists.  Otherwise this would have been a compilation error.

Comment: Why not use commons-io library? See [Commons-io listFiles Example](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-get-all-files-with-certain-extensions-in-a-directory-including-subdirectories.html) if you can use commons-io library instead writing your own method.

Comment: @Ramu I have limited ram on my servers and commons-io is quite big and if I am honest I don't think its needed at all.

Comment: @user12346306 Do not change this question to a total different question, otherwise the answers given to you before the change doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: @Progman, I'll keep that in mind, but I was just pointing out about a well established API which was written specifically for usage like this. That is all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of the problem is simple:  `Arrays.asList` returns a list that doesn't allow you to add or remove elements.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) says this:

> *"Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)"*

Fixed-sized means that you can't add or remove elements.  (That would change the list size!)

So if you want to be able add elements to `l` you need to use a `List` class that supports adding elements; e.g.

```
List<File> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dircList));
```

---

However, that will give you another problem.  Your code is modifying `l` while you are iterating it.  That will give you a `ConcurrentModificationException` for a non-concurrent queue.  You *could* use a concurrent queue, but then there is the problem that the API doc's don't guarantee that the iteration will "see" new elements added a during the iteration.

The clean solution to the CME problem is to use a `Queue` or `Deque` instead of a `List`.

---

> I you look at my edit you will see the new error I am guessing, using a Queue did actually fix the first error I was getting.

You are still iterating the list.  You need to use the methods of the `Queue` API; e.g.

```
    Queue<File> q = ...
    File c;
    while ((c = q.poll()) != null) {
        if (c.isDirectory()) {
            for (cc : c.listFiles()) {
                q.offer(cc);
            }
        } else {
            children.add(c);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will give this a shot once I am home, I see why the issue is occurring now however, thanks for the help.

Comment: If you look at my edit you will see the new error I am guessing, using a Queue did actually fix the first error I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a workaround(as you requested in the Edit), to make your method work, use this. Otherwise, for your actual question, @Stephen C answer is the correct one.

```
public static Set<File> iterateDirectory(String dir) {
        Set<File> children = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        File dirc = new File(dir);
        File[] dircList = dirc.listFiles();
        List<File> l = new ArrayList<File>();
        for (File c : dircList) {
            if (c.isDirectory()) {
                children.addAll(iterateDirectory(c.getAbsolutePath()));
            } else {
                children.add(c);
            }
        }
        return children;
    }
```

If you don't need to maintain the insertion order, then you can replace the LinkedHashSet with HashSet.